# Modify flow file attributes in NiFi with Python sys.stdout?

Tags: python, apache-nifi

In my pipeline I have a flow file that contains some data I'd like to add as attributes to the flow file. I know in Groovy I can add attributes to flow files, but I am less familiar with Groovy and much more comfortable with using Python to parse strings (which is what I'll need to do to extract the values of these attributes). The question is, can I achieve this in Python when I use `ExecuteStreamCommand` to read in a file with `sys.stdin.read()` and write out my file with `sys.stdout.write()`?

So, for example, I use the code below to extract the timestamp from my flowfile. How do I then add `ts` as an attribute when I'm writing out `ff`?

```
import sys

ff = sys.stdin.read()
t_split = ff.split('\t')
ts = t_split[0]

sys.stdout.write(ff)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing back the entire file again, you can simply write the attribute value from the input FlowFile

```
sys.stdout.write(ts) #timestamp in you case
```

and then, set the `Output Destination Attribute` property of the `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor with the desired attribute name.

Hence, the output of the stream command will be put into an attribute of the original FlowFile and the same can be found in the original relationship queue.

For more details, you can refer to [ExecuteStreamCommand-Properties](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html#:%7E:text=Output%20Destination%20Attribute,the%20output%20attribute.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not importing any native (CPython) modules, you can try ExecuteScript with Jython rather than ExecuteStreamCommand. I have an example in Jython in an [ExecuteScript cookbook](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922). Note that you don't use `stdin`/`stdout` with ExecuteScript, instead you have to get the flow file from the session and either transfer it as-is (after you're done reading) or overwrite it (there are examples in the [second part of the cookbook](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-2/ta-p/249018)).

Comment: Thank you so much I'll take a look at those links. But, if I end up needing non-native modules, this is or is not possible with `stdin`/`stdout`?

Comment: it's not possible to set attributes through ExecuteStreamCommand.